# Kayak like URL instead of query parameters

Tags: ember.js

I have a small app which reads parameters from the URL.

Example: http://localhost:4200/flights?from=FRA&to=JFK

I'd like to offer the user a Kayak like URL like:
http://localhost:4200/flights/FRA-JFK

Can this be done with Ember without doing the mapping in the webserver?

**app/controllers/flights.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['from','to'],
  from: null,
  to: null,

  filteredFromFlights: function() {
    var from = this.get('from');
    var flights = this.get('model');

    if (from) {
      return flights.filterBy('from', from);
    } else {
      return flights;
    }
  }.property('from', 'to', 'model'),

  filteredFlights: function() {
    var to = this.get('to');
    var flights = this.get('filteredFromFlights');

    if (to) {
      return flights.filterBy('to', to);
    } else {
      return flights;
    }
  }.property('from', 'to', 'model')
});
```

Comment: I have an ember rails app I wrote a while back that does just this. How ever I'm on my phone right now so I will leave you with the github repo. https://github.com/kiwiupover/kiwi-flights/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add nested route (say `from-to`), so `flights` route is responsible for finding `flights`, `from-to` route is responsible for local filtering `flights` by param.

```
//router
this.route('flights', function() {
   this.route('from-to', {path: '/:from_to'});
});

//flights route
model: function() {
  return this.store.find('flight');
}

//from-to route
model: function(params) {
  var splited = params.from_to.split('-');
  return {
    from: splited[0],
    to: splited[1],
    model: this.modelFor('flights'); 
  };
},
setupController: function(controller, models) {
   controller.setProperties(models);
}

//from-to controller
filteredFlights: function() { 
  //...
}.property('from', 'to', 'model.[]'),

filteredFromFlights: function() { 
  //...
}.property('from', 'to', 'model.[]'),
```